# emacs feature similar to netbeans templates?

Tags: templates, emacs, netbeans

In netbeans you can store some code as template and call it back whenever you like by typing a specific word and TAB..is there a similar emacs feature, and if yes how can I use it?
thanks in advance!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are a couple of libraries that come with emacs that provide this kind of functionality.  [SkeletonMode](http://www.emacswiki.org/cgi-bin/wiki/SkeletonMode) and [TempoMode](http://www.emacswiki.org/cgi-bin/wiki/TempoMode) both allow you to insert templates into your code.  They can be combined with [AbbrevMode](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/AbbrevMode) to automatically trigger on keywords, like in NetBeans.

[Yasnippet](https://code.google.com/p/yasnippet/) is a much more full-featured library to do the same, bundled with lots of defaults for various languages.  It is not currently bundled with emacs.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, take a look here : http://code.google.com/p/yasnippet

In addition, you can watch this video : http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=76Ygeg9miao

Comment: thanks, do you have any experience with installation on Carbon emacs?I am following instructions and it doesn't seem to work...

Comment: problem solved!for some reason file needed to be load in the beginning of .emacs, maybe there was a conflict with flymake but I'm not really sure about it...

Answer (score 0):

I used to use [ELSE Mode](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/ElseMode) very heavily when I was doing a lot of programming by voice.